# Return 1 if select outputs rows

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to write a function that returns 1 if a select queries outputs one or more rows and return 0 if the select query returns 0 rows. How can I do this?

Comment: use [ROW_COUNT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/row_count/)

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: @Roy gave you an example. Just click on the link he provided. Or google 'row count sql'.

Comment: @Roy ROW_COUNT always return -1 for SELECT that returns result set. It doesn't matter if the result set is empty or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use [`CASE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM table WHERE ...
```

You can also combine [`IF()`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php) with [`COUNT()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_count.asp) like this

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 1, 0) FROM table WHERE ...
```

Comment: This is my select query `(SELECT * FROM build WHERE ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) EXISTS (SELECT * FROM processor_products pp, motherboard m where pp.Socket <> m.Socket))` I need to return 1 if rows exist?

Comment: It's hard to say what are you exactly trying to do from your query. Your query's syntax is completely wrong. My guess is that you are trying to check if there is a build that has processor and motherbord with different socket. Am i right? You should update your question, add the structure of your `build`, `processor_products` and `motherboard` tables and exact description what are you trying to get. That way i or someone else can help you with complete query you need.

Comment: You understood my query exactly right. If a such a build does exist, which my query will output. If such a row exists I want my function to return 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coalesce()` and `limit` to return if there's a result or not.

```
select coalesce((select 1 from tableA where col1='value' limit 1), 0)
```